# Returning text to default state (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, text, back

I've attempted to collect text fields in my document and replace it with different text (language). Which went fine, but I'm not able to return it back without reloading a page.

Firstly, all text fields I wish to replace have property called `lang="en"`.

So I've used jQuery `.each()` function to collect all of them into a array doing following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[lang=en]").each(function(){
   var textArray = $(this).text();
   });
});
```

While variable textArray holds collection of required text fields to be replaced with another variable. Example:

```
var replaceText = textArray.replace("Hello", "Hi").replace("Good afternoon!", "Hi!");
```

While inside each function I can do `$(this).text(replaceText)` to apply replaced text, but I wish to do it with button click (`button1`) while another button (`button2`) will change it back.

Inside button onclick event (inside each loop function) `$["lang=en"].text(replaceText);` does not have correct effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert"/>
<input type="button" id="convert-back" value="Convert Back"/>
```

---

`#convert` will convert your text in all input files which has `lang=en` property. `#convert-back` button will do the reverse. Let me know if it's working for you

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#convert").click(function () {

        $("input:lang(en)").each(function () {

            var textArray = $(this).val();
            var replaceText = textArray.replace("Hello", "Hi").replace("Good afternoon!", "Hi!");
            $(this).val(replaceText)
        });
    });

    $("#convert-back").click(function () {

        $("input:lang(en)").each(function () {

            var textArray = $(this).val();
            var replaceText = textArray.replace("Hi", "Hello").replace("Hi!", "Good afternoon!");
            $(this).val(replaceText)
        });
    });

});
```

---

**Edit**

HTML Part

```
<input type="text" lang="en" value="Hello" alt="Hello, stack"/>
<input type="text" lang="en" value="Hello" alt="Hello, over"/>
<input type="text" lang="en" value="Hello" alt="Hello, flow"/>
<input type="text" lang="en" value="Hello" alt="Hello, stack"/>
<input type="text" lang="en" value="Hello" alt="Hello, over"/>

<input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert"/>
```

Jquery Part

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#convert").click(function () {

        $("input:lang(en)").each(function () {

            var textArray = $(this).val();
            var newArray = $(this).attr("alt");

            $(this).val(newArray);
            $(this).attr("alt", textArray);
        });

        if ($(this).val() == "Convert") { $(this).val("Convert back"); } 

        else { $(this).val("Convert"); }
    });

});
```

Stored old value into `alt` tag of input box to replace again. Let me know if it's helpful to you.

Comment: I've actually did it like this, but there is no way to do the "convert-back" without rewriting values in replace? I've quite long .replace list. Like store defaults somewhere in different function?

Comment: We've to store old value somewhere like in hidden box to retrieve again.

Comment: Edited my answer, check and let me know if you are looking for something like this

Comment: Actually using alt property for text is a good idea, I check it out.

Comment: I've tried it using properties lang-def and lang-alt and everything is working properly, thanks for awesome idea. But, you should change your edit code, it swaps value and alt ? why ? I wish to replace text not the property, so $(this).text(newArray); & $(this).text(textArray) works.